# How can I convert Future data to a list of double?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I'am trying to read the records in order to create a dashboard , but the thing is I don't know how to read the data from what I got from database , please could someone help me , here is the code

```
 Future dataline() async {

        final dao1 = Provider.of<CommandeDao>(context);

        List<GeneratorCommandeResult> liste = await dao1.GeneratorCommande();
        return liste;
  }

  Material mychart1Items(String title, String priceVal,String subtitle) {
    Future liste  = dataline() ;


    return Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 14.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
      shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: new Sparkline(
                      data: liste,
                      lineColor: Color(0xffff6101),
                      pointsMode: PointsMode.all,
                      pointSize: 8.0,
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `FutureBuilder` widget with async operation like `dataline` function.

Example

```
FutureBuilder<double>(
          future: liste,

          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData?Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                    child: new Sparkline(
                      data: snapshot.data,
                      lineColor: Color(0xffff6101),
                      pointsMode: PointsMode.all,
                      pointSize: 8.0,
                    ),
                  ):CircularProgressIndicator();
                  //the CircularProgressIndicator
                 //is used to indicate the data hasn't come yet
          },
        ),
```

add this FutureBuilder in the children parameter of the column.

**Note** : in the sparkLine widget the data parameter recieve the snapshot.data not the liste that you have declared . because your liste is of type Future which holdes data of type double , while the snapshot has the actual data which in this case is the double list.
I hope that helps

Comment: the data type is list of double and the snapshot.data is double , it gives me an error on that @karim tarek

Comment: because  of that line  `List<GeneratorCommandeResult> liste = await dao1.GeneratorCommande(); return liste;` the return type of the function is `GeneratorCommandeResult` not `List<double> , so i suggest you to specify the type of each future you have to <List<double>> like `Future<List<double>> liste = dataLine() , even the return type of the dataLine function to determine where that error comes from

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a table of dogs with columns `id`, `name`, and `age` then after retrieving the rows of all dogs from the table in the form of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, map them back to Dog objects as follows:

```
// A method that retrieves all the dogs from the dogs table.
Future<List<Dog>> dogs() async {
  // Get a reference to the database.
  final Database db = await database;

  // Query the table for all The Dogs.
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('dogs');

  // Convert the List<Map<String, dynamic> into a List<Dog>.
  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return Dog(
      id: maps[i]['id'],
      name: maps[i]['name'],
      age: maps[i]['age'],
    );
  });
}
```

Note: the code sample is from flutter documentation.

Mapping your list which contains `double` values could be done similarly.

Comment: for my case it won't return the object which you specified there Dog